# Using boost::chrono, how to calculate milliseconds since epoch UTC from separate year, month, day, hour,min,secs

Tags: c++, boost, c++-chrono

I am given the values for year, month,day,hour,minute and second in UTC. I need to calculate the milliseconds since the epoch (UTC).

How can this be achieved?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have to do it in `boost::chrono`?  It's not really well suited for `boost::chrono` (perhaps `boost::posix_time` or `boost::gregorian` would be better). That's trivially easy using what's provided in `<ctime>` (presuming you mean the UTC "unix timestamp epoch".

Answer (score 6):

**If** you can neglect [leap seconds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_seconds), this is quite easy with the right tools.

You will need:

1. `days_from_civil` located [here](http://home.roadrunner.com/~hinnant/date_algorithms.html#days_from_civil).
2. A custom `duration` type representing days == 24 hours (shown below).
3. C++11's `std::chrono` or `boost::chrono` library (I'm showing it with `std::chrono`).

Here is how you create a custom `chrono::duration` that represents 24 hours:

```
typedef std::chrono::duration
<
    std::int32_t, std::ratio_multiply<std::chrono::hours::period, std::ratio<24>>
> days;
```

Now you are ready to write your function:

```
std::chrono::milliseconds
ms_since_UTC(int year, int month, int day, std::chrono::hours h,
             std::chrono::minutes m, std::chrono::seconds s)
{
    return days(days_from_civil(year, month, day)) + h + m + s;
}
```

`days_from_civil` will convert your `year/month/day` into the number of days since New Years 1970 (the UTC epoch).  Your custom `duration` `days` will seamlessly interoperate with the "pre-defined" chrono durations: `hours`, `minutes`, `seconds`, and `milliseconds`.  All of these durations will implicitly convert to `milliseconds` with no truncation error.

If you need to take [leap seconds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_seconds) into account, then you will need to build a table of `{days, chrono::seconds}`, where the second part of the entry is the cumulative number of leap seconds you need to add to the duration if the current value of `days` is on or after the `days` entry in the table.

```
static constexpr std::pair<days, std::chrono::seconds> leap_seconds[25] =
{
    std::make_pair(days(days_from_civil(1972, 7, 1)), std::chrono::seconds(1)),
    // ...
};
```

Then you will need to search that table (using `std::find_if`, or `std::lower_bound`) to see if the return from `days_from_civil` lies prior to the table, within the table, or beyond the table.  If prior to the table you add 0 leap seconds.  If within the table, you add the appropriate number of leap seconds according to the table entry.  If beyond the table you add (currently) 25 leap seconds.

```
return d + h + m + s + ls;
```

This is a "high maintenance" solution in that the table in this code will need to be updated every time they decide to add a leap second to UTC.  It should also be noted that this solution can't be used with high confidence more than about 6 months in the future because one simply does not know if a leap second will be added (or subtracted) further in the future than that.

The `days_from_civil` code is in the public domain, so feel free to use it.  It is efficient.  And it has a +/- range of about 5.8 million years when given 32 bit signed inputs (so you don't really have to worry about breaching its range of validity).  [The paper](http://home.roadrunner.com/~hinnant/date_algorithms.html) goes into the gnarly details of how the algorithm works if you are interested.

Comment: Is `days_from_civil` or something similar in the STL or in Boost?

Comment: @Albert: Definitely not in the std::lib.  boost has boost::datetime, and its own implementation of <chrono>.  However my paper is the only source I'm aware of of this particular formulation.  If you search the web you can find similar formulas elsewhere, though not this exact one.  My paper is the only one I'm aware of which clearly defines the range of validity of the formula.  You (or anyone else) are free to take this formula and use it however you choose.  I consider it in the public domain.